# Button events hover/active also affect other form buttons

Tags: html, css, styles

I have some CSS that attempts to do a pressed in button effect on either "active" or "hover" events but for some bizarre reason, the CSS from the event also appears to affect other buttons which are not being hovered or active.

See below example - when you hover over any of the three buttons, the others margins get changed and move up/down when they shouldn't be affected at all.

What's going on?

```css
    input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
        color: #000000;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: visible;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        /*box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 #CCCCCC inset;*/
        box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 0 rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) inset;
        border-collapse: separate;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 3px 13px 6px 13px;
        position: relative;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        background-image: none;
    }

    input[type="submit"]:hover,
    input[type="button"]:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 #CCCCCC inset;
        margin-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        background-image: none;
    }
```

```html
    <center>

    <input value="Yes, submit now!" name="button" type="submit">
                <!-- WARNING: value of button is checked on next page -->
                <input value="No, enter more details" name="button" type="submit">
                <input value="Exit" name="button" type="submit">
    </center>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well they move because one of them get's margin-top:4px , so they all move after that element

i suggest you use `transform:translateY(4px)` instead of `margin-top:4px` on `:hover`

see snippet below

```css
input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
        color: #000000;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: visible;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        /*box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 #CCCCCC inset;*/
        box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 0 rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) inset;
        border-collapse: separate;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 3px 13px 6px 13px;
        position: relative;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        background-image: none;
    }

    input[type="submit"]:hover,
    input[type="button"]:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 #CCCCCC inset;
        transform:translateY(4px);
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        background-image: none;
    }
```

```html
<center>

    <input value="Yes, submit now!" name="button" type="submit">
                <!-- WARNING: value of button is checked on next page -->
                <input value="No, enter more details" name="button" type="submit">
                <input value="Exit" name="button" type="submit">
    </center>
```

Comment: Your suggestions work. I didn't realise that they were inline, and that if a margin in any inline changes, that everything on the line moves up or down. I suppose it makes sense if you think of them as some sort of text. I would prefer to use your firt option, but how compatible is this with old browsers - I never used or heard of that transform method before...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform scroll down to Browser compatibility . the `CSS transform property` is very often used with all it's values `scale,translate,rotate` . some `values` like `matrix3d` or `perspective` etc. are not so well supported. but `translate` surely is. use it with confidence